# Redirect one url to https - .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have been browsing around trying to find a simple way to redirect 1 url to https://

To be more clear, I am trying to do:

`http://www.google.com/page-name/` to go to `https://www.google.com/page-name`

I found many solutions out there but were all customized to the sites spec. Would it be a simple

redirect XX XX

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you mean redirecting all the pages to a single page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to force **every** page to https then following code will work for you in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

#### EDIT or to force https on just a specific page `securedpage.html` use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^securedpage\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```